# Error when getting values from SQLite table

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

**EDIT :** Turns out I made a silly typo , Thanks for helping out !

I want to get the values form an sqlite table , I used `fetchnone()` to get the last row value . But I am getting an unknown error when calling that function

```
'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fetchnone'
```

Here's my code for redirect function and I can't figure out where the error is

```
@app.route('/<short_url>')
def redirect(short_url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('url.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    result_cur = cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM WEB_URL WHERE S_URL = ?;" ,(short_url,) )
    try:
        redirect_url = result_cur.fetchnone()
        print redirect_url

        conn.close()
        return redirect(redirect_url)   
    except Exception as e:
        error  = e 
        return render_template('index.html' , error = error)
```

Thanks!

EDIT :

I know this is against some rules of Stackoverflow , But I'd like to ask another question regarding redirection :

I am trying to build a URL shortener , but I am having error when redirecting user to the longer URL . I have used SQLite for database . 
Here's my redirection code:

```
@app.route('/<short_url>')
def redirect(short_url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('url.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    result_cur = cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM WEB_URL WHERE S_URL = ?;" ,(short_url,) )
    try:
        redirect_url = result_cur.fetchone()[0]
        print redirect_url

        conn.close()
        return redirect(redirect_url , code = 200)  
    except Exception as e:
        error  = e 
        return render_template('index.html' , error = error)
```

The `fetchone()[0]` does return the correct long URL , but on clicking the generated short URL I'm getting this error

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

There shouldn't be a `NoneError` because I'm getting a value from the db.

Comment: [Clippy] Did you mean [`fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone)?

Comment: yes , I have used fetchnone()[0]

Comment: You have fetch **none**, you want fetch **one**.

Comment: yep , I noticed Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post a new question rather than editing this one.

Comment: Cannot post within 90 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typo: **fetchone()** is right method.

Reference : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone